# AttributeError: nonetype object has no attribute 'find'

Tags: python, html, beautifulsoup, attributeerror

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests

job_request = requests.get('https://www.google.com/search?q=Software+engineer+&sxsrf'
                           '=ALiCzsaeLLjcCHZk46ernxCkoay7ldkDsA:1666897166012&source=hp&ei=DdVaY-CHOvvgkPIPxc2m6Ag'
                           '&iflsig=AJiK0e8AAAAAY1rjHgG0CdqkcKPC3aVnmBvSGuZgc6Py&uact=5&oq=Job+listings&gs_lcp'
                           '=Cgdnd3Mtd2l6EAMyBwgjEMkDECcyCggAEIAEEIcCEBQyDQgAEIAEELEDEIMBEAoyDQgAEIAEELEDEIMBEAo'
                           'yBQgAEIAEMgUIABCABDIFCAAQgAQyCggAEIAEELEDEAoyDQgAEIAEELEDEIMBEAoyDQgAEIAEELEDEIMBEAo6BAg'
                           'jECc6BQgAEJECOgsILhCABBCxAxCDAToLCAAQgAQQsQMQgwE6CwguEIAEEMcBENEDOg4ILhCABBCxAxCDARDUAjoLCC'
                           '4QgAQQsQMQ1AI6EQguEIAEELEDEIMBEMcBEK8BOggIABCABBCxAzoHCAAQgAQQCjoICAAQyQMQkQI6EAgAEIAEEIcCE'
                           'LEDEIMBEBQ6DQgAEIAEEIcCELEDEBQ6CwguELEDEMcBENEDOhMILhCABBCHAhCxAxDHARDRAxAUOgsILhCABBDHARCv'
                           'AToICC4QgAQQ5QRQAFjbFGDEFWgCcAB4AYABoQGIAcYLkgEEMy4xMJgBAKABAQ&sclient=gws-wiz&ibp=htl;jobs'
                           '&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwijh7Dti4H7AhXzkWoFHddJCAMQudcGKAJ6BAgNEC8#fpstate=tldetail&htivrt=jobs&ht'
                           'idocid=4XlU2-oL0UgAAAAAAAAAAA%3D%3D').text

beautify = BeautifulSoup(job_request, 'lxml')
listing = beautify.find('li', class_ = 'iFjolb gws-plugins-horizon-jobs__li-ed')
company = listing.find('div', class_ = 'oNwCmf').text
```

I am new to HTML and web scraping, I am not sure how exactly the 'div' tags are found by BS4. Any help would be appreciated. The end goal is to scrape the listings from a site and eventually import them to a DB.

Comment: There's nothing wrond with your code, it's just that there is no div with the class `oNwCmf` in the html. You'll probably need to include a user agent to get proper code returned. You could check out working [examples](https://github.com/Nv7-GitHub/googlesearch/blob/master/googlesearch/__init__.py) for inspiration

Answer (score 0):

The error is likely because `listing`  has a  value of  `None`  - because the first `find` returned nothing. When working with requests+beautifulsoup, you should make a habit of checking what `requests` returned when your code doesn't behave as expected. Use

```py
with open('x.html', 'w', encoding="utf8") as f:
    f.write(str(job_request))
```

to save `job_request` to a file named "x.html" which can be opened to view what kind of response you have received. For me, it just looks like
[image]

If you see the same thing, you can probably resolve it just by adding some [headers](https://datagy.io/python-requests-headers/) to your request - for me, it was enough to just add [User Agent](https://www.useragentstring.com/Chrome104.0.5112.79_id_19986.php)

```json
headers = {"user-agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_15_7) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/104.0.5112.79 Safari/537.36"}
```

but I think the closest you can get to imitating your browser is to [copy the request from your browser](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HULbR.png) and then use [curlconverter](https://curlconverter.com/) to get python code you can paste into your own.

---

Even so, you'll probably notice that only the first 10 results are in the fetched html - the rest are populated with JavaScript and [probably] APIs; if you want more than the first ten - and/or if adding headers doesn't work for you - you might have to resort to something like [selenium](https://medium.com/featurepreneur/an-introduction-to-web-automation-using-selenium-python-2ad84814b11c)...